How to pass a template as it is to child component
I want to pass a template as it is to child component in vue3. e.g.
// Grid.vue
<template>
    <dx-data-grid />
</template>

// Parent.vue
<template>
    <Grid>
        <template #abc><h1>Hello</h1></template>
    </Grid>
</template>

Now what I want is that template #abc should be passed as it is to dx-data-grid, so Grid.vue should be generated like
<dx-data-grid>
    <template #abc><h1>Hello</h1></template>
</dx-data-grid>

Why I need this is, dx-data-grid is some 3rd party component and it works when it has template #abc inside it. But I want to make it more generic so that parent component can pass the template name and content dynamically.

This can be achieved by passing the template content dynamically from the parent to the child component and then we need to inject it into the third-party component dx-data-grid.
For this we need to made modifications in the Grid.vue and Parent.vue file.
Grid.vue:
In this we need to define a slot in the dx-data-grid component where we need to insert the dynamic content. In this case, we have named the slot abc this can be modified as per the need.
<template>
  <dx-data-grid>
    <!-- We have used v-slot to inject the slot dynamically. -->
    <slot name="abc"></slot>
  </dx-data-grid>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Grid',
};
</script>

Parent.vue:
We have used the <template> element with a v-slot directive to define the content for the abc slot. This content will be passed to the Grid component and can be rendered inside the dx-data-grid.
<template>
  <Grid>
    <template #abc>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </template>
  </Grid>
</template>

<script>
import Grid from './Grid.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Grid,
  },
};
</script>


Use slots as below:
// Grid.vue
<template>
    <dx-data-grid>
        <template #abc>
            <slot name="abc"/>
        </template>
    </dx-data-grid>
</template>

// Parent.vue
<template>
    <Grid>
        <template #abc><h1>Hello</h1></template>
    </Grid>
</template>


Please explain how this solves the issue. "Try this" is not an answer - [answer]
